# Why is the columnName property in IDataErrorInfo returning an empty string?

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik-grid, idataerrorinfo

I am developing a WPF application using the .NET 4.0 Framework and using a telerik RadGridView to display an assortment of data. The RadGridView is bound to an Observable Collection populated from a SQL database. I am using IDataErrorInfo to handle row validation however when I step through the code, most of the columnNames appear to be empty strings event though I know that is not the case. I am defining the validation as follows:

```
public partial class DataRow : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetResult(columnName);
        }
    }

    private string GetResult(string columnName)
    {
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "Column1":
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Column2))
                {
                    return "Error";
                }
                break;
            case "Column2":
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Column3))
                {
                    return "Error with Column 2";
                }
                break;
            case "Column3":
                break;
            case "Column4":
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Column4))
                {
                    return "Column 4 is not null or empty";
                }
                break;
            case "Column5":
                if (this.Column5 <= 0)
                {
                    return "Column 5 must be greater than zero";
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

DataRow's members are defined in the SQL database. I have run and stepped through the code and consistently am getting to Column1 validation and Column3 validation but when any other column is called, columnName is an empty string. I know this is the case because when I modify the validation rule to be as follows:

```
private string GetResult(string columnName)
{
    switch (columnName)
    {
        case "Column1":
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Column2))
            {
                return "Error";
            }
            break;
        case "":
            return "This column is in error";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get an error on Column2, Column4 and Column5.

I have so far been unable to find if anybody else has had this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!